# Crear un Array con números aleatorios y que no se repitan en Swift 4

Tags: array, swift4

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: necesito generar un array con números aleatorios, pero que no se repitan los números, agradecería vuestra ayuda, muchas gracias.

```
for contador in 1...10
{
    numerosAleatorios = Int.random(in: 1...100)
    arrayNumeros.append(numerosAleatorios)
    numerosAleatorios = 0
}
 arrayNumeros.sort()
 print(arrayNumeros)
```

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es, después de generar el número aleatorio y antes de introducirlo, comprobar que ese mismo número no esté ya en el array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genera los números consecutivos y después les cambias el orden

```
var array: [Int] = []
//en este for no se repiten los números
for i in 1...10 {
   array.append(i)
}
//cambio el orden
array.shuffle()
```

Otra alternativa si quieres que no sean consecutivos. Seria ir generando números aleatorios por tramos

```
var array: [Int] = []
//z es el ultimo numero generado, para marcar el rango del que se extraen números aleatorios
var z = 1
for i in 1...10 {
   z = Int.random(in: z...(i*10))
   array.append(z)
   //incremento z para impedir que el ultimo numero se repita
   z += 1
}
```

Otra version, a ver si no tiene tantas criticas. Se saca un elemento, se busca si esta en el array y si no lo esta se incluye

```
while (array.count < 10) {
   //genera un numero entre 1 y 1000
   let z = Int.random(in: 1...1000) 
   //busca si esta ese numero. ndx seria un array con las veces que aparece el numero
   let ndx = array.filter({$0 == z})
   //si no tiene elmentos, es que no lo encontró, así que lo añado
   if ndx.count == 0  {
        array.append(z)
   }
}
```

Comment: Para el primer ejemplo, si tienes que generar 10 números entre 1 y 1.000.000, tendrías que llenar y desordenar un array de 1.000.000 de elementos para recoger solo 10. Es una animalada. Para el segundo ejemplo, normalmente los números aleatorios se consideran que deben ser *independientes* entre sí, con tu método no lo son (solo puede haber un número "aleatorio" en cada rango; si tienes 1,14,25,33,42,58,69,71,88 sabes que el que queda está en el rango 90-99).

Comment: el primero te genera una lista de 10 elementos de 10 posibles, no genera 1.000.000 en ningún sitio y no elige de esa lista ninguno, solo los desordena. Con respecto al segundo, puede salir el 1, el segundo elemento sera entre 2 y 20, puede salir el 2, el tercero sera entre el 3 y el 30, puede salir el 3... Es otra forma, en ningún sitio he dicho que sean las únicas. Piden 10 números aleatorios sin que se repitan y esto no se repite y son aleatorios

Comment: Si te fijas en la pregunta, el OP está interesado en sacar 10 números aleatorios entre 1 y 100, así que ni siquiera respondes a esa posibilidad. Y por supuesto, si mañana necesita sacar 10 números aleatorios entre 1 y 1,000,000,000, pues tu invento es lentísimo.

Comment: bueno, la primera opción nuca va a dar esta opción, ya que solo da los 10 elementos desordenados, la segunda si o si va ha hacer 10 iteraciones, y la ultima puede dar 10 iteraciones, 11, si alguno se repite, 12, 13, etc, no lo veo tan lento, pero bueno, puede poner tu opción, esto es libre para que todo el mundo aporte

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, @Spidvmp ,la ultima respuesta es justo lo que buscaba, lo he estado probando y funciona muy bien como tu dices saca un elemento comprueba si esta en el array y si no esta lo incluye, muchas gracias.